# Scatterpoints not aligned with labels in a forest plot

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to create a forest plot in Excel, following this website, [How to Make a Forest Plot in Excel (2 Suitable Examples)](https://www.exceldemy.com/make-a-forest-plot-in-excel/).  I am having some issues: The scatter dots are not aligned with the labels on the side.

Also, there is an error bar that is too large and makes it difficult to read the shorter error bars. How can I fix that?

Picture of my graph:

[image: Picture of my graph]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example page you provided takes an easy concept and makes it significantly more difficult than it needs to be.

**The Main Problem:**  The issue you appear to have is aligning the bar chart and scatterplot components.  This is common with bar/scatter combinations because the bar (and column, and line) chart types use categories for their axis, while scatter points use numeric values.

**The Solution:**  You have 12 categories for the bar chart, so to most easily properly align the scatterplot points, you should format your scatterplot Vertical(Y) Axis to Minimum: 0 and Maximum: 12.  Then change your Points (assuming you followed the demo's naming convention) to intervals of 1.0, starting at 0.5 so {0.5, 1.5, 2.5...11.5}.
This is necessary because the first category ("Etá" in your example) is centered between 0 and 1, therefore the associated point needs a value of 0.5, and all the other values follow that convention.

[image]

**A Better Alternative:**  Use a pure scatterplot chart.  To accomplish the same chart above:

1. add one additional "helper" column to your data and fill it with 0's.
2. create a new, blank scatter chart
3. add your primary data series, with your data as the horizontal (x) and their corresponding point value as the vertical (y).
4. add a second series to be your labels, using the helper column (0's) as the horizontal (x) values and the corresponding point values as the vertical (y) and format the Markers to None.
5. add data labels for the second series and format to get Value From Cells and select your data labels also, adjust Label Position to Left.
6. format to taste

**Your Other Problem:**
*As a new member here I'm compelled to tell you that typically you should limit each post to a single question.*  But here's a quick answer: there's not much you can do.  It's an Excel chart, and those are your values.  That said, here's three options:

1. Leave it as is.  This is the most accurate view of your data, as frustrating as it may be.
2. Focus on the low values by truncating your horizontal axis in a way that highlights the low values by sacrificing your larger values.
3. Chart them separately in a trellis or multiple configuration where each series gets its own scale.  This makes them harder to compare but provides accurate representations of each series.
4. [Bonus] If your readers are sophisticated enough, you can convert your horizontal axis to a logarithmic scale.  Not great for combo charts, but can accurate (if not easy to read) values for all scales.  Assuming no 0 or negative values in your data.